# Basic Solenoid Question

Tags: solenoid-valve, mechanical, humidity

I have a super simple question about solenoids.

If I wired [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CGHTDJJ), a 120v solenoid valve, to a 3 prong male plug would [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077FPTWLY) cheap chinese humidity controller be able to control it?
My assumption is yes, but I am mainly wondering if there is anything egregious that I am missing.

edit:this and that clarification

Comment: Please no "this" and "that" links. Provide all of the required information inline. Links might point to some complementary information.

Comment: @Hairball, you are asking all your readers to follow two links to Amazon ads - probably with no datasheets available - instead of doing the work and posting the photos and relevant specs (into the question) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the humidity controller works as advertised, yes this should work fine. These things just have a relay inside them to open/close contacts to mains 120VAC. You're well within the current rating (0.2A valve vs 10A socket).